# Scraping url using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract url but they gave me these error `Ignoring response <403 https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/ca>: HTTP status  code is not handled or not allowed` these is the page link https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/ca

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/countries/ca']

    
   
    def parse(self, response):
            books = response.xpath("//div[@class='card__desc']//a[starts-with(@href, '/online')]").extract()
            for book in books:
                    url = response.urljoin(book)
                    print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem resides in using `extract()`. Try using `extract_first()` or `extract[0]` instead.

Another problem could be the way you wrote the xpath expression. The expression: `//div[@class='card__desc']//a[starts-with(@href, '/online')]` seems to retrieve the `<a>` element and not the url that's contained in it.

Try:

```
//div[@class='card__desc']//a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your user agent instead of the default user agent

In settings.py

```
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36
```